# Self-absorbing subsets in a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

From [planetmath](https://planetmath.org/AbsorbingSet)

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ equipped with a non-discrete valuation $|\cdot|:F\to \mathbb{R}$. Let $A$ and $B$ be two
> subsets of $V$. Then $A$ is said to absorb $B$ if there is a
> non-negative real number $r$ such that, for all $\lambda \in F$ with
> $|\lambda| \geq r$ , $B \subseteq \lambda A$.

I am thinking about those subsets that can absorb themselves.

1. A subset consisting of a single nonzero vector cannot absorb itself,
   but a subspace can. I was wondering if it is possible to
   characterize those subsets that can absorb themselves? Must such a subset
   contain the zero vector? Must it be a subspace?
2. Same questions for open subsets in a topological vector space.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: It certainly need not be a subspace, take a ball around zero for example. As for characterizing the self-absorbing subsets, there's no hope. Just try to draw a few pictures in $\mathbb{R}^2$... For example, every bounded set containing a neighborhood of zero is self-absorbent. Or the union of any number of rays starting from the origin (those rays need not contain zero).

Comment: There was a now deleted comment asking for an open subset not containing $0$ which is self-absorbing: try $V \smallsetminus \{0\}$, for example.

Comment: @t.b.: Thanks! Sorry, I deleted my comment because I saw your modification to your first comment. In a topological vector space, is a neighborhood of zero always self-absorbing?

Comment: No: $(-1,1) \cup (2, \infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Yes if it is bounded.

Comment: @t.b.: Thanks! How about a connected neighborhood of zero?

Comment: No. Take the union of a ball with the graph of $\sin{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is my last comment on this thread.